# Toggling the active class to change the font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dashboard where I have placed the `font-awesome` icons. I want to toggle between plus and minus when the dashboard item is clicked. But when I try to do that only the first item is getting toggled even when I click other dashboard items.

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  /*$(".dropdown").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");*/

  if ($('#plusMinus').hasClass('fa-plus-square')) {
    $('#plusMinus').hasClass('fa-plus-square')
    $('#plusMinus').removeClass('fa-plus-square');
    $('#plusMinus').addClass('fa-minus-square');
  } else {
    $('#plusMinus').removeClass('fa-minus-square');
    $('#plusMinus').addClass('fa-plus-square');

  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dashBoard animated slideInLeft">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 1<span><i class="fa fa-plus-square" id="plusMinus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 2<span><i id="plusMinus" class="fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Module 3<span><i id="plusMinus" class="fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Identifiers in HTML must be unique** Your HTML is invalid. I would recommend to add a common class i.e. `plusMinus` and then use it.

You need to target element in current element i.e. `this` context and use [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to descendant of current element and the use [`$.fn.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".plusMinus").toggleClass('fa-plus-square fa-minus-square');
});
```

*HTML*

```
<i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".plusMinus").toggleClass('fa-plus-square fa-minus-square');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dashBoard animated slideInLeft">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 1<span><i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 2<span><i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Module 3<span><i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this was the best and easiest answer of all.. Thanks for the additional `toggleClass` made it much simpler

Answer (score 3):

You are using `id`s to select your icons. HTML `id`s are supposed to be unique in a page ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)), and when you try to select them with jQuery, you always get the first one it meets (see the [jQuery ID selector docs](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)).

To solve your issue, select the icons by starting from the clicked element using [jQuery's `.find` method](https://api.jquery.com/find/), and not the whole document, and use `class`es instead of `id`s:

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
    var button = $(this).find('.plusMinus');

  if (button.hasClass('fa-plus-square')) {
    button.removeClass('fa-plus-square');
   button.addClass('fa-minus-square');
  } else {
    button.removeClass('fa-minus-square');
    button.addClass('fa-plus-square');

  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dashBoard animated slideInLeft">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 1<span><i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 2<span><i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Module 3<span><i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your control you used a common `ID`, and ID's can't be more than one, so JQuery find always the first element. If you want to get the clicked element you have to use `this`, look at this example:

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  /*$(".dropdown").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");*/

  if ($(this).find("#plusMinus").hasClass('fa-plus-square')) {
    $(this).find("#plusMinus").hasClass('fa-plus-square')
    $(this).find("#plusMinus").removeClass('fa-plus-square');
    $(this).find("#plusMinus").addClass('fa-minus-square');
  } else {
    $(this).find("#plusMinus").removeClass('fa-minus-square');
    $(this).find("#plusMinus").addClass('fa-plus-square');

  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dashBoard animated slideInLeft">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 1<span><i class="fa fa-plus-square" id="plusMinus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Module 2<span><i id="plusMinus" class="fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Module 3<span><i id="plusMinus" class="fa fa-plus-square "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```